# how to remove symbols from a list and then put it back?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

So I have to make a code that reads from a txt file and then I convert the txt into a list to analyze it(transform units). What I want to do is remove the punctuation from specific words from the list in order to analyze it and then place it black in the same places as before. This list can always change cause the code has to work for every txt I give.

How do I place the symbols back exactly on the places the were before? I cannot use any packages for this.

```
punct=['?', ':', ';', ',', '.', '!','"','/']
size = {'mm':1, 'cm':10, 'm':100, 'km':1000}
with open('random_text','r') as x:
    LIST=x.read().split() 
    for item in LIST:
        if item[:-1] in size.keys() and item[-1] in punct:
            punct_item=item
            non_punct_item=item[:-1]
            symbol=item[-1]
```

Comment: Copy the original, remove what needs removal, delete the copy when finished.

Comment: What do you mean delete the copy when finished. Sorry i' very new on this.

Comment: append it in a different list if it meets you condition. Which list will you be working with?

Comment: You shouldn’t name a variable `list` or `size`, and certainly not `LIST`.

Comment: @ Alexander Cécile that's not the point here. The names are just for the shake of the post.

Answer (score 2):

Well reading a file won't change anything to it, so if you read the file once and make all the modifications you want (remove the punctuation in this case). Then when you need the punctuation again just reread the file again and everything should be in the same position.

A faster approach would be:

```
punct=['?', ':', ';', ',', '.', '!','"','/']
size = {'mm':1, 'cm':10, 'm':100, 'km':1000}
# Do all modifications you need 
words_temp = None
with open('file1.txt','r') as file:
    words = file.read().split() 
    words_temp = words
    for item in words:
        if item[:-1] in size.keys() and item[-1] in punct:
            punct_item=item
            non_punct_item=item[:-1]
            symbol=item[-1]

words = words_temp
del words_temp
```

That was the simpler way of doing it, another way is implementing a dictionary with the key being the index of the character to be removed and the value is the character itself. For this approach you will need to iterate once over the whole file to build this dictionary, then iterate once again to add them back. 
Sample code...

```
tracker = dict()
punct=['?', ':', ';', ',', '.', '!','"','/']
words = list("If it walks like a duck, and it quacks like a duck, then it must be a duck. I love python!")
print("".join(words))
# If it walks like a duck, and it quacks like a duck, then it must be a duck. I love python!

# Removing the punct. 
i = 0
while i < len(words): 
    if words[i] in punct:
        tracker[i+len(tracker.keys())] = words[i]
        words.pop(i)
    i+=1


print("".join(words))
# If it walks like a duck and it quacks like a duck then it must be a duck I love python

# Adding the punct back 
for k,v in tracker.items():
        words = words[:k] +  [v] + words[k:]

print("".join(words))
# If it walks like a duck, and it quacks like a duck, then it must be a duck. I love python!
```

Comment: Reading in a file multiple times is not going to be faster than almost anything you do in memory

Comment: I think this might depends on the file size, keep in mind we're iterating and checking every character in the file twice, it might be interesting to create a test bench and see the time difference.

Comment: Disk I/O will always be slower than an in-memory copy unless you run out of memory.

Comment: I posted the results I got @MadPhysicist , keep in mind reading the file twice will allow you to skip multiple iterations over the file while being more efficient in memory usage.

Comment: If you make a copy of the file as soon as you read it in, there is no place where you need to read it in twice.

Comment: True in this case it would be faster with more memory consumption, thanks for the notice let me update the code 

Comment: I've flipped my vote. While I generally consider unnecessary file I/O to be bad advice, you've really taken the time to understand and quantify what you're dealing with, making this a very good answer overall.